# Стриминг аудио с Android на Android

Tags: android, android-sdk

Хочу узнать возможно ли передавать аудио, которое воспроизводится в смартфоне на другой смартфон через wi-fi? 
Ведь возможен же стриминг с ПК на Андроид.

Что нужно для реализации этого дела?

Answer (score 1):

На одном устройстве открыть поток воспроизведения, на другом устройстве принять поток, и соответствующие программы для подачи и принятия потока на данных устойствах.